# trigger all stage in gitlab pipeline manually once

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

How can i trigger all the stage after a click.
like
when: manual
but for all stage at once that i don't have to add the when to all stages.

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

when: manual

test:


deploy:
```

something like this.
Thanks in advance

i tried this didnt work. is there a way to trigger it once and it runs all the stages

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

when: manual

test:

deploy:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no stage level controls in GitLab CI. However, you can arrange a meta-stage for a single `manual` approval job to allow all jobs in the subsequent stage(s) to run.

```yaml
stages:
  - approve_test
  - test
  - approve_deploy
  - deploy


.approval:
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "noop"

approve_test:
  extends: .approval
  stage: approve_test

approve_deploy:
  extends: .approval
  stage: approve_deploy

# ...
```